# boundingRectWithSize adds extra bottom padding to UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, uifont, cgrect

UILabel is created like this:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 10, 268, 44)];
label.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentLeft;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
label.numberOfLines = 2;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Then to update the label I do this:

```
label.text = someText;
CGRect frame = label.frame;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: label.font};
CGRect rect = [someText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:attributes
                                          context:nil];
frame.size.height = rect.size.height;
label.frame = frame;
```

This works fine with the label only has one line of text, but I have a maximum of two lines. When the 2nd line gets truncated, extra bottom padding gets added to the label, which makes it impossible to position the label below it (the red label in the images):

[image]

[image]

Why does this happen? If it's a bug, is there a workaround?

Comment: did you find a fix for that? @soleil

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
UILabel *anotherLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
[anotherLabel setAttributedText:attrString];
[anotherLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
[anotherLabel setText:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[anotherLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[anotherLabel sizeToFit];
[myLabel setAttributedText:attrString];
[myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, [anotherLabel frame].size.height)];
```